# How to filter ListBox item ?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I define this simple class

```
 public class SimpleClass
 {
      public string Val1 {get;set;};
      public string Val2 {get;set;}
      public string Res
      {
            get
            {
                 string.Format("{0}_{1}", Val1, Val2 );
            }
      }

      public SimpleClass(string v1, string v2)
      {
             Val1 = v1;
             Val2 = v2;
      }

      public SimpleClass(string v1, int i)
      {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                 Val1 = v1;
                 val2 = "";
            }

            if(i == 0)
            {
                 Val2 = v1;
                 val1 = "";
            }
      }


 }
```

Now, i define in the code this

```
 List< SimpleClass > myList = new List<SimpleClass>();
 myList.Add(new SimpleClass("a1", "b1");
 myList.Add(new SimpleClass("a2", "b2");
 myList.Add(new SimpleClass("a3", "b3");
 myList.Add(new SimpleClass("a4", "b4");
```

And i define in the xaml 2 ListBox - 
     First  that show all the a1...a4 items 
     Second that show all the b1...b4 items

Each item in the ListBox is CheckBox - and the content is the string of the item.

Now i want to define filter that will show in some other list only the SimpleClass.Res that was checked in the listBox.

==> that mean that if in the listBox that items that was checked are b1 and a3 that the only text in the third listbox will contain

```
       a1_b1
       a3_b3
```

How can i do it ?

I trying to use the CollectionViewSource but i can't define multi filter in this cases.

Comment: What is the individual `CheckBox` bound to?

Comment: Nothing. just filter from the text that appear on the CheckBox

Comment: Are you trying to achieve multi selection? If so then the checkbox must be bound to something isnt it?

Comment: lets say that i have already method that convert the checkbox bound to some string. and now i need to filter the items of the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UI you will have to have the checkbox bound to something so that you are **aware** of the status of the checked items from both ListBoxes.

Hence we bind it `TwoWay` to the ancestor `ListBoxItem`'s `IsSelected` property. This way when checkboxes are checked they automatically register the checked item under `ListBox.SelectedItems` property.

Based on this we perform multi binding `ListBox3.ItemsSource` to `ListBox1.SelectedItems` and `ListBox2.SelectedItems`. The multi value converter called `MergeSelectedItemsHelper` simply performs a union of the two selected items lists.

*I have used `Array` of `TextBlock` instead of `List` of `SimpleClass` to bind to all those ListBoxes.*

**XAML:**

```
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

        <StackPanel.Resources>

            <x:ArrayExtension x:Key="MyArraySource" Type="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <TextBlock Text="A" Tag="A1" DataContext="A_A1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="B" Tag="B1" DataContext="B_B1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="C" Tag="C1" DataContext="C_C1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="D" Tag="D1" DataContext="D_D1"/>
            </x:ArrayExtension>

            <local:MergeSelectedItemsHelper 
                  x:Key="MergeSelectedItemsHelper"/>                

            <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBox1ItemTemplate">
                <CheckBox 
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                            AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                  Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Content="{Binding Text}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBox2ItemTemplate">
                <CheckBox
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                             AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                  Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Content="{Binding Tag}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1"
                 SelectionMode="Extended"
                 Margin="10"
                 ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyArraySource}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBox1ItemTemplate}"
                 SelectionChanged="ListBox1_SelectionChanged">
        </ListBox>

        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox2"
                 SelectionMode="Extended"
                 Margin="10"
                 ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyArraySource}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBox2ItemTemplate}"
                 SelectionChanged="ListBox1_SelectionChanged">
        </ListBox>

        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox3" Margin="10" DisplayMemberPath="DataContext">
            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MergeSelectedItemsHelper}">
                    <Binding Path="SelectedItems" ElementName="ListBox1"/>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedItems" ElementName="ListBox2"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code Behind:**

Now as `ListBox.SelectedItems` property is simply a non dependency property and also non-observable so the bindings **will not** automatically **refresh**. In code behind we will hage to refresh the binding when seletion is changed on the `ListBox1` and `ListBox2`.

```
    private void ListBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bndexp = BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression(
                         ListBox3, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);
        if (bndexp != null)
        {
            bndexp.UpdateTarget();
        }
    }
```

As said earlier, the multi value converter simply joins the selected items together and gets called when multi-binding is refreshed...

```
public class MergeSelectedItemsHelper : IMultiValueConverter
{

    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(
           object[] values,
           Type targetType, 
           object parameter, 
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        var list1 = values[0] as IList;
        var list2 = values[1] as IList;

        var validList2 = list2 ?? new List<object>();

        return list1 != null
                 ? list1.Cast<object>().Union(validList2.Cast<object>())
                    : validList2.Cast<object>();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
           object value,
           Type[] targetTypes,
           object parameter,
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Put a boolean public property in SimpleClass and bind it to the checkbox.  Then in the second list bind visibility to the property.

```
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DispDetail, Mode=OneWay}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </DataTrigger
```

Answer (score 1):

If your checked items are in your ViewModel, you can simply filter the collection view source using a delegate

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.myList);
view.Filter = obj =>
{
    var sc = obj as SimpleClass;

    // Do your checks to see if this object is valid, and return a bool
    // For example,
    return SelectedOptions.Contains(sc.Val1) || 
           SelectedOptions.Contains(sc.Val2);
};

return view;
```